# How to resolve a conflict with a system scope dependency jar

Tags: maven

I have a jar that my code depends on and it is located locally on my PC.

That jar contains the *'org.apache.commons.lang3'* package but an older version or a version that contains the class 'StringUtils' but without all of its methods.

In my maven pom, I am using the *'org.apache.commons.lang3'* dependency also but at runtime I get the error *'NoSuchMethodError'* which means that during runtime it is using the commons.lang3 version of the jar and not the one from my dependency.

Is there a way to force it to use the dependency in my pom file?

Here is how my pom looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <test.path>C:/Users/user/test</test.path>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dep</groupId>
            <artifactId>dep</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${test.path}/dep.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <!-- build fat jar file with dependencies -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>dep-included</shadedClassifierName>
                    <outputDirectory>${test.path}/out</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**CONCLUSION FROM COMMENTS:**
It is not possible to remove such packages in a jar with Maven. I have to manualy edit and remove the packages from the jar file.

***Thank you all for taking the time to answer!***

Comment: open that "jar" (with a zip tool), and get rid of these (outdated) "contents". I fear, maven won't/still can't do it.

Comment: Classpath order matters. How are you running the program, using what commands? Can you see and edit the resulting classpath? Try putting the commons-lang3.jar first in your classpath. And yes, this specific problem is partially what "JAR hell" is.

Comment: Can the dependency in question not be excluded by specifying it in the `<exclusions></exclusions>` tag as shown [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#dependency-exclusions)?

Comment: First cleanup/fix your code to remove the usage of that old stuff and use official releases instead of something homebrewn stuff..Furthermore I strongly recommend not to use shade-plugin to create a jar which will be used later as a dependency that will cause many issue (not today but you will stumble upon them)...

Comment: @DebarghaRoy I have tried that and it doesn't work. It's not a dependency that I can exclude but a fat jar that contains the same package that I want to use.

Comment: @MichailAngelos You need to edit the JAR itself, you cannot exclude the packages with Maven alone.

Comment: @JFabianMeier This seems to be the only way indeed. Thanks!